# border-radius on images.. (rounded corners)

Tags: image, rounded-corners, css

Trying to add rounded corners to images, that also have a border.

Came up with the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/tgqBG/

But it doesn't look good at all with the whitespace below the image, and the fact that the corners of the border and image don't match. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,
Wesley

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden;` to `.thumb_container`, add `vertical-align:bottom;` to the image.

You can remove a lot of the other values, here is an updated jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tgqBG/12/

Another way of doing this (supported by more browsers) is showing the image through `background-image`. In my comment I said this would pose a problem because the element needs fixed dimensions, however I just realized this can easily be fixed by also putting the image in there but hiding it.

http://jsfiddle.net/tgqBG/51/

This doesn't work without `float` because it will get a width of `100%`. This is because of `div`'s automatic property to be rendered as a `block`.

To fix this, change `div` to `span` and then add `display:inline-block;`.

http://jsfiddle.net/tgqBG/52/

Comment: This is not looking too good in Safari.  Square image corners are on top of rounded border corners.

Comment: Yep, square corners in safari and that's the browser I need to support the most.

Comment: Wesley: try setting z-index to -1 on the image in Kokos' example.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't check Safari. One way I did this on one of my own sites was by using a `div` that had rounded corners and contained the image as a `background-image`. This also works in Safari. The problem with this is that your element needs fixed dimensions. http://jsfiddle.net/tgqBG/50/

Comment: @Andreas Carlbom - Did that, made no difference.

Comment: @Kokos - Can I ask why you specify the image also as <img src="" />, is there a special reason for that?

Comment: Oh, just noticed your updated answer, thanks. This seems to work.

Comment: Too bad it's reliant on float though, would like to use this type of effect (without specifying image dimensions) without float as well.

Comment: If you change the element from a `div` to a `span` and give it `display:inline-block;` it will work without float as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should take into account that an element that is smaller than its container (the image) should have a smaller corner radius for it to be aligned with the outer elements corner radius (meaning have the same curvature). Try something like 15px for the image border-radius. That seems to work for your example.

Comment: Problem is that I can't test this for every image and every size as the images are loaded dynamically and the only thing that is provided is that the border-radius should be x px.

Comment: I was just saying this from a design standpoint. :) This is something you can't avoid if you want to nest elements. Your best bet would be to either only set the radius on the outer element and have it clip the image, or apply the border to the image itself and get rid of the div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/tgqBG/39/

The inner image is smaller, and thusly needs to have a smaller border-radius. Margins and paddings default to 0. Avoid floats like the plague. Vertical-Align:top alings the image correctly.